# Remove array elements and add them back to where they were

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, addition

I am trying to remove elements from arrays while remembering their position and add them back later. So far I have this piece of code:

```
var my_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var removed_elements = [];

// Assuming letter provided exists in my_array
function remove_element(letter) {
    for (var index in my_array) {
        if (my_array[index] == letter) {
            break;
        }            
    }
    var removed_element = {
        index: index,
        letter: letter            
    }
    removed_elements.push(removed_element);
    my_array.splice(index,1);
}

// Assuming letter provided exists in removed_elements
function add_element(letter) {
    for (var index in removed_elements) {
        console.log('test');
        if (removed_elements[index].letter == letter) {
            console.log(removed_elements[index]);
            break;
        }            
    }
    my_array.splice(removed_elements[index].index,0,removed_elements[index].letter);
}
```

It works fine as long as I remove 1 element at a time and add it back before removing another one. However, when I start removing  several elements consecutively, the index saved for removed elements (not first one, but subsequent ones) becomes relative to the state of `my_array` at the time of removal, and not absolute to `my_array`'s initial state, which can cause problems.

For instance if you remove `'B'` and `'D'` and add `'D'` and `'B'`, you end up with `['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'D']` instead of `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`.

[Here is a jsfiddle showing what the problem is](http://jsfiddle.net/eGx32/)

**What modifications should I change for `my_array` to end up in its initial state no matter of many elements I remove or add and how?**

I thought about storing information about which elements surround the removed element at the time of removal and use that as extra info when adding back but wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure this is very possible. I don't know how you're actually using this code, but think about the order of events. If certain letters are removed and put back in before other ones, it won't matter what "original" information you store about each removed letter - there's no guarantee that the array's current state is anything like the original. If your requirement is that certain letters are removed at once, and then you put them all back at once, that shouldn't be bad. If there's no specific order of things happening, this should be tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't actually remove them at all:

```
var my_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var removed = [];

function remove_element(letter) {
    var i = my_array.indexOf(letter);

    if(i > -1) {
        removed.push(i);
    }
}

function add_element(letter) {
    var i = my_array.indexOf(letter);

    if(i > -1) {
        removed.splice(removed.indexOf(i), 1);
    }
}

function get_array() {
    return my_array.filter(function(x, i) {
        return removed.indexOf(i) === -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: That's the way to go :) `jsFiddle` available for those who want to test: http://jsfiddle.net/enSqv/